# Excel recognizes as correct an utf-8 encoded file (in Import Data) but failed to open it correctly

Tags: excel, csv, import, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to open an utf-8 encoded csv file in Excel for Windows 10.

When opening it directly, characters appear wrong. If I go to the Data menu >>Import Data, a window with the dataset appears, showing that the file has the correct utf-8 encoding, with the characters appearing ok.
How I force Excel to open it directly considering that the file is ok and is already recognized as that by the program?

Thanks!

I've gone using the common solution, as it is, go to Data >> Import Data, etc, and instead of seeing a wrong encoding, the Import Data window shows me that the dataset is correctly recognized as an utf-8 encoded file, showing the correct characters.
I don't understand why, if Excel recognizes it, when I try to open the csv file directly, it always appears wrong.

Comment: When opening text files, Excel assumes a localized default encoding, unless a UTF-8 BOM is present. Generate or convert the file to UTF-8 w/ BOM encoding, and Excel will open it correctly

Comment: In addition to above, Excel will also try to be "friendly" and guess delimiters and quoting for you (based on current system locale). So a comma delimited file will open in USA, but not in Germany.  Very annoying that the "import data" can't be default on opening CSV. Or, that you can't set a default data format to use each time.